# VTK - Migrating from 6.1 to 8.2 [2]

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, vtk

Please see this post:

[VTK - Migrating from 6.1 to 8.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55108817/vtk-migrating-from-6-1-to-8-2/55153865#55153865)

I setup all settings, and I get only 3 errors, and I cannot get rid of them for days:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: MyApp, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>   Creating library F:\MyApp\x64\Debug\MyApp.lib and object F:\MyApp\x64\Debug\MyApp.exp
1>MyAppView.obj : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol ??0vtkMFCWindow@@QEAA@PEAVCWnd@@@Z (public: __cdecl vtkMFCWindow::vtkMFCWindow(class CWnd *)) imported in function "protected: __int64 __cdecl CMyAppView::OnPostInit(unsigned __int64,__int64)" (?OnPostInit@CMyAppView@@IEAA_J_K_J@Z)
1>MyAppView.obj : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol ??1vtkMFCWindow@@UEAA@XZ (public: virtual __cdecl vtkMFCWindow::~vtkMFCWindow(void)) imported in function "public: virtual void * __cdecl vtkMFCWindow::`scalar deleting destructor'(unsigned int)" (??_GvtkMFCWindow@@UEAAPEAXI@Z)
1>VTKView.obj : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol ?DrawDC@vtkMFCWindow@@QEAAXPEAVCDC@@@Z (public: void __cdecl vtkMFCWindow::DrawDC(class CDC *)) imported in function "public: virtual void __cdecl CVTKView::OnDraw(class CDC *)" (?OnDraw@CVTKView@@UEAAXPEAVCDC@@@Z)
1>vtkRenderingOpenGL2-8.2.lib(vtkOpenGLState.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_SymGetLineFromAddr64 referenced in function "class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __cdecl getProgramStack(void)" (?getProgramStack@@YA?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@XZ)
1>vtkRenderingOpenGL2-8.2.lib(vtkOpenGLState.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_SymInitialize referenced in function "class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __cdecl getProgramStack(void)" (?getProgramStack@@YA?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@XZ)
1>vtkRenderingOpenGL2-8.2.lib(vtkOpenGLState.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_SymFromAddr referenced in function "class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __cdecl getProgramStack(void)" (?getProgramStack@@YA?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@XZ)
1>F:\MyApp\x64\Debug\MyApp.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 3 unresolved externals
1>Done building project "MyApp.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

cand you give a hint to gt away of these links errors ?

Answer (score 2):

- Link your binary with `dbghelp.lib`

  e.g. add something like the following line into your CMakeLists.txt if you are using CMake

  `target_link_libraries(${project_name} PRIVATE dbghelp.lib)`

  or add it into into project (Linker/Input/Additional Dependencies) if you are not using CMake

  or the add the following into main.cpp somewhere below includes

  `#pragma comment(lib, "dbghelp.lib") //untested`
- Possibly turning off VTK error logging in VTK CMake may help as well (not sure)

  `VTK_REPORT_OPENGL_ERRORS [ ]`